# show that $\frac{dw}{du} = \frac{u+w+1}{u-w+3}$ can be solved by means of the substitution $w-1 = y, u+2 = t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on exercises from the book *Differential equations and mathematical biology 2d ed.* by Jones, Plank, and Sleeman. I'm confused with the expected answer for exercise 1.8(a):

**use the substitution $w-1 = y, u+2 = t$ to show that**

$$\frac{dw}{du} = \frac{u+w+1}{u-w+3}$$

**can be solved**

I'm confused with the words "can be solved", since after I applied the indicated substitution, and assumed naively that $dw = dy, du = dt$, I got to the equation

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{t+y}{t-y}$$

To my understanding, this is an **inexact equation**, for which there exists a solution method, namely finding some integrating factor which makes the equation **exact**. *Is this enough of an answer? or should I be able to find an explicit solution?* As for the latter, I failed to find such an integrating factor, because I got to the PDE $$\mu_y(t+y) + 2\mu + \mu_t(t-y) = 0$$
and I don't know how to go forward from there.

I might have made dumb mistakes along the way, I'm quite a novice in these topics.

I would hugely appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that the transformation reduces the RHS of the equation to a quotient of two polynomials homogeneous of the same degree. I'm sure you've heard about how to deal with those. In this case you will make another substitution $y=tx,$ which will now convert the equation into a separable one, and then you'll be done.

Comment: Thank you very much @Allawonder, your advice helped me to find an explicit solution!

Comment: @DanielRiBR1011101 You're welcome. :)